# Download a pdf from Chrome Viewer using selenium python

Tags: python, pdf, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to log into an application, navigate to a pdf link, click on it. The pdf opens in chrome viewer. Download the pdf file. Download part is getting error: "DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)" and the pdf does not get downloaded

I've looked at all the solutions online and am doing something wrong. New to this.

Please correct me. Any help is much appreciated!

```
from time import sleep
import self as self
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

*# mulitple drivers for other aspects of the code. Not relevant to the question so excluded.*

WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver = WebDriver.get("open application") *(links changed)*

*#click on pdf file*
wait = WebDriverWait(WebDriver, 10)
WebDriver.find_element(By.ID, "XXXX").click() **(ID excluded as its restricted to post)**

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": "C:/Downloads/POD",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)
WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

1. You've defined multiple Chromedriver instances. You should only need one.
2. `WebDriver.get()` doesn't return anything but you've assigned it to `driver`.
3. You've defined your `ChromeOptions()` after you've already created one driver instance.
4. `DeprecationWarning` is not an error, it's a warning. It's basically telling you that you're using code in a way that's not going to be supported in the near future.

Your code should look something like

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": "C:/Downloads/POD",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)
WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
WebDriver.get("http://www.sample.com")
#click on pdf file
WebDriver.find_element(By.ID, "someId").click()
```

Comment: I have no idea if this will actually download the PDF because you haven't provided a link to the page or relevant HTML but this should get you started with some of the initial issues. For answers to the rest, you'll need to ask a new question.

Comment: It worked! I'm sorry to be unable to share links due to office policy. Thanks for explanation points and updated. It helped me understand better. Thanks JeffC!

Comment: If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: HI JeffC, Thanks for posting it! I tried to upvote your answer right away but  got a message which prevented my profile as it needs 15 reputation points to be able to upvote it. As this is my first question, i don't have that many points, my apologies! It said that my response has been recorded and it's not only currently. Hope this helps! :)